# .bat file with filename input

Tags: filenames, bcc

I want to create a `.bat` file which gets the filename and processes a command like: `make.bat <filename>`. The `.bat` file must accept the command in following format:

```
"gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror %filename% -lcs59 -lm -o %filename%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, "how do I take command line arguments to a batch file I'm writing", you probably want `%1` for the first argument, `%2` for the second, and so forth. A good page explaining this is [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php). Many other batch file concepts are also well explained on that site.